# ASP.NET MVC Multiple(forms and windows) authorization models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, authorization

I would like to create asp.net mvc 4 application where is two authentification.
One would be forms auth and second windows auth by the Active Directory user login.

It's possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you most certainly can use multiple.....

First setup your web.config to point at windows form
You will then go through the testing of your integration with AD user auth you could have it with SSO or not,  but multiple auth is done is many places with mvc 4 etc...

also here is another provider option too

[What's difference between windows and forms authentication in asp.net mvc 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842274/whats-difference-between-windows-and-forms-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-4/15845541#15845541)